# ElasticSearch creating index

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

ElasticSearch was installed and configured. When this method runs

```
    private void IndexCreate(CreateIndexDescriptor desc)
    {
        var output = Client.CreateIndex(_indexName, c => desc);
    }
```

I receive this error in `output.DebugInformation`

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on PUT: /loc_%240_stag_6_%241_vpx42fux3zcvabhayt4u8wwfdsea_%242_aqjpvvxtfsyaqfb0vobhhycwba0a
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.1559947
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.    at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at Elasticsearch.Net.HttpConnection.Request[TResponse](RequestData requestData)
# Request: {"settings":{"max_inner_result_window":1000,"index.number_of_replicas":1,"analysis":{"analyzer":{"standard_analyzer":{"type":"custom","char_filter":["remove_symbols_char_filter"],"filter":["lowercase"],"tokenizer":"standard"},"ngram_analyzer":{"type":"custom","char_filter":["remove_symbols_char_filter"],"filter":["lowercase","ngram_filter"],"tokenizer":"standard"},"prefix_analyzer":{"type":"custom","char_filter":["remove_symbols_char_filter"],"filter":["lowercase"],"tokenizer":"keyword"}},"char_filter":{"remove_symbols_char_filter":{"type":"pattern_replace","pattern":"/","replacement":""}},"filter":{"ngram_filter":{"type":"edge_ngram","min_gram":1,"max_gram":20}},"normalizer":{"lowercase_keyword_normalizer":{"type":"custom","filter":["lowercase"]}}},"index.number_of_shards":1},"mappings":{"segmentdocument":{"properties":{"segmentKey":{"type":"text"},"segmentGroup":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"},"tags":{"type":"text"},"displayName":{"type":"text","fields":{"ranked":{"type":"text","analyzer":"standard_analyzer","search_analyzer":"standard_analyzer","index_options":"positions","norms":true},"ngram":{"type":"text","analyzer":"ngram_analyzer","search_analyzer":"standard_analyzer","index_options":"positions","norms":false},"prefix":{"type":"text","analyzer":"prefix_analyzer","search_analyzer":"prefix_analyzer","index_options":"positions","norms":true},"keyword":{"type":"keyword","ignore_above":256}},"analyzer":"standard_analyzer","search_analyzer":"standard_analyzer","index_options":"docs","norms":false},"displayNameNaturalSort":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"},"attributes.physicalrepresentation":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.mlsid":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.mlskey":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.officename":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.officemlsid":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.officemlskey":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.firmmlskey":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.icon":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.category":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.city":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.namefirstlast":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.namelastfirst":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.activeagentcount":{"type":"double","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.isactive":{"type":"boolean","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.blank":{"type":"text","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}},"attributes.datapointcount":{"type":"double","fields":{"keyword":{"type":"keyword","normalizer":"lowercase_keyword_normalizer"}}}}}}}
# Response: {"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [segmentdocument : {properties={attributes.activeagentcount={type=double, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.mlsid={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.city={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.blank={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.physicalrepresentation={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, displayName={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=false, analyzer=standard_analyzer, type=text, fields={prefix={search_analyzer=prefix_analyzer, norms=true, analyzer=prefix_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, ranked={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=true, analyzer=standard_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, ngram={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=false, analyzer=ngram_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, index_options=docs}, segmentGroup={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}, attributes.namelastfirst={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.datapointcount={type=double, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, tags={type=text}, attributes.namefirstlast={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officemlsid={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.category={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, displayNameNaturalSort={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}, attributes.icon={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officename={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, segmentKey={type=text}, attributes.mlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officemlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.isactive={type=boolean, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.firmmlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}}}]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [segmentdocument : {properties={attributes.activeagentcount={type=double, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.mlsid={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.city={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.blank={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.physicalrepresentation={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, displayName={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=false, analyzer=standard_analyzer, type=text, fields={prefix={search_analyzer=prefix_analyzer, norms=true, analyzer=prefix_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, ranked={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=true, analyzer=standard_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, ngram={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=false, analyzer=ngram_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, index_options=docs}, segmentGroup={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}, attributes.namelastfirst={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.datapointcount={type=double, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, tags={type=text}, attributes.namefirstlast={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officemlsid={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.category={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, displayNameNaturalSort={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}, attributes.icon={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officename={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, segmentKey={type=text}, attributes.mlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officemlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.isactive={type=boolean, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.firmmlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}}}]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [segmentdocument : {properties={attributes.activeagentcount={type=double, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.mlsid={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.city={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.blank={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.physicalrepresentation={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, displayName={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=false, analyzer=standard_analyzer, type=text, fields={prefix={search_analyzer=prefix_analyzer, norms=true, analyzer=prefix_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, ranked={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=true, analyzer=standard_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, ngram={search_analyzer=standard_analyzer, norms=false, analyzer=ngram_analyzer, type=text, index_options=positions}, keyword={ignore_above=256, type=keyword}}, index_options=docs}, segmentGroup={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}, attributes.namelastfirst={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.datapointcount={type=double, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, tags={type=text}, attributes.namefirstlast={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officemlsid={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.category={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, displayNameNaturalSort={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}, attributes.icon={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officename={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, segmentKey={type=text}, attributes.mlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.officemlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.isactive={type=boolean, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}, attributes.firmmlskey={type=text, fields={keyword={normalizer=lowercase_keyword_normalizer, type=keyword}}}}}]"}},"status":400}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the version of ES that your using?

If you are using the lastest version of ES, this will not work as mapping type has been removed from ES 7 onwards, see [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html).

If you need mapping type to be available you could use previous versions of ES and it will work fine.

Alternatively, a temporary solution to use ES 7 with mapping type is to add:

```
?include_type_name=true
```

in the URL.

Comment: I'm using version 7.1.1. If I rollback to version 6, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

Check your **index name in ES Cluster**.I think already you have a mapping for the given index.Now you try to creating a duplicate one that's why error throwing.